# Converting Unicode characters to latex code?

Tags: math-mode, unicode

I'm no expert in Latex, just a frequent user. I found an old file of mine with code of this sort:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{color,pxfonts,fix-cm}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage[mathletters]{ucs}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{32}{$\ $}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{46}{\textperiodcentered}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{960}{$\pi$}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{60}{\textless}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{124}{\textbar}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{8804}{$\leq$}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{8805}{$\geq$}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{62}{\textgreater}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{58}{$\colon$}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{8217}{\textquoteright}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{8776}{$\approx$}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{183}{$\cdot$}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{8220}{\textquotedblleft}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{8221}{\textquotedblright}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{8222}{\quotedblbase}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{171}{\guillemotleft}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{215}{$\times$}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{8730}{$\surd$}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{8734}{$\infty$}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{8594}{$\rightarrow$}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{177}{$\pm$}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{8216}{\textquoteleft}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{8801}{$\equiv$}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{945}{$\alpha$}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{34}{\textquotedbl}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{8658}{$\Rightarrow$}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{161}{\textexclamdown}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{191}{\textquestiondown}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{187}{\guillemotright}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{8211}{\textendash}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{167}{$\S$}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{952}{$\theta$}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{955}{$\lambda$}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{946}{$\beta$}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{948}{$\delta$}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{966}{$\varphi$}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pict2e}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage[margin=0in,paperwidth=612pt,paperheight=792pt]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\definecolor{color_29791}{rgb}{0,0,0}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay]\path(0pt,0pt);\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{picture}(-5,0)(2.5,0)
\put(181.247,-108.236){\fontsize{24.787}{1}\usefont{T1}{ptm}{m}{n}\selectfont\color{color_29791}Solutions}
\put(292.943,-108.236){\fontsize{24.787}{1}\usefont{T1}{ptm}{m}{n}\selectfont\color{color_29791} }
\put(302.047,-108.236){\fontsize{24.787}{1}\usefont{T1}{ptm}{m}{n}\selectfont\color{color_29791}Manual}
```

and it goes on for hundreds of pages (literally). Can I recover the original Latex code from this? When I typeset this using Latex/LualaTex/XeLatex some characters are missing and the file looks corrupted. How can I fix this?

Comment: Missing characters could be due to missing glyphs in the font you are using. You should check the log file (in Lualatex missing character messages are like that: `Missing character: There is no ... (U+XXXX) in font ...`

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. What do you mean with 'recover the original Latex code', what do you expect the original code to look like? Also, what goes on for hundreds of pages (also, what is a page in your editor?), the `\put` statements, or something else? If your question is about all the `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter` statements, then these are actually intended to make the source _easier_ to read, by allowing Unicode characters directly in the source (e.g. `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{8776}{$\approx$}` allows you to type/use ≈ in your document and then LaTeX will interpret that character as `$\approx$`).

Comment: `Can I recover the original Latex code from this? ` do you have any reason to suspect that is not the source?

Comment: I suspect the code is actually generated by GeoGebra/some other tools etc.. so the "source" is not LaTeX. Nevertheless it's usually difficult to "decompile" things.

Comment: Something odd though, `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter`  takes hex values but you are showing decimal, so that is not the standard `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter` (oh, `ucs` package hmm.....)

Comment: the markup is for pdflatex not lualatex or xelatex

Comment: Dear everyone: Thanks for all this input! I don't get it all, but I'll start with Iacobus1983. Yes, in the log file I see stuff like:                                            
Missing character: There is no â€ (U+2264) in font ptmr8t!
What can I do now?

Comment: @Marijn: Thanks, this is heavy. Based on the above information I was expecting to see stuff like "{\bf Solutions Manual}", the way I would ordinarily write a Latex file. The \put statements go on for hundreds of pages. I guess I have a font problem as standard math characters are missing from the output, but I don't know what font to call.

Comment: @David Carlisle: I was hoping to see something more standard/elementary, like if I'm just writing an article in Latex. e.g., $x^2+y^2 = z^2$ as an equation without the \put commands. I have never seen this output before, sorry.

Comment: @User202729 Bummer, I have to think about how to fix the output so it's readable and all math characters are in.

Comment: You may find it easier to start from a clean empty preamble, ignoring the one you show which is using `ucs` package and `\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}` neither of which work well in current latex, then just copy in any text and math to your new document, ignoring all the `\put` which are positioning things by coordinate (perhaps written by hand, perhaps with a graphical editor, but which are "source" as far as latex is concerned.)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140803/discussion-between-david-carlisle-and-angelo).

Comment: Oky, so I found out that that the original file was converted from pdf to Latex by a software company called Aspose. I wrote to them about the problem but never got an answer. I still can't get main math characters to appear correctly :(